# Is it possible to stop fork failure here

Tags: c, operating-system, fork, system-calls

I am given this code and was told to run it. After some researching, I think that this is `fork` bomb, and eventually there will be fork failing here.

In my opinion, I think this happens mainly for reasons related to memory, according to the `[EAGAIN]` x2 and  `[ENOMEM]` in the man page.

> However, I have a question of whether if
>
> a)it is possible to make this code not have fork failing on LINUX
>
> b)theoretically is there something I can do to the OS to make the fork failing stop while still having the semantics of `fork()` be preserved.

My current response to the question is to perhaps find a way to recycle the pids to allow unlimited memory, but I'm not sure of my answer. Can anyone help me out?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define D 10000

double delay(unsigned long loops) 
{
    unsigned long i;
    double z = i, y;

    z = i;
    for (i = loops; i >= 1 ; i--) {
        y = ((double) loops)/((double) (loops - i + 1));
        z = (y*y + z)*i/((double) loops);
    }
    return z;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int child;

    while (1) {
        if ((child=fork()) > 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "[%d] ", getpid());
        else if (child == -1)
            fprintf(stderr, "FAIL ");
        else delay(D); // Pick some large D to start with
    }
}
```

Comment: The `delay` function has some other problems because `i` is used uninitialized.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It sounds like you are asking for a way to fork an infinite number of processes.  Since a process requires some memory, and your system has a finite amount of memory, that is fundamentally impossible.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`  when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: in the function: `delay()`, the variable `i` is used uninitialized.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std-gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: OT: regarding: `double z = i, y; z = i;` This is trying to initialize the double variable `z` from the (uninitialized) integer variable `i`.    Suggest 1) initialize `i` to some known value  2) only do that once 3) to avoid a warning from the compiler about the implicit conversion from `int` to `double` (at least) cast `i` to `double`

Comment: OT: pids have a type: `pid_t`  Currently, that is the same as `int`, but that can change in the future.  Suggest using `pid_t child;` rather than `int child;`

Comment: in general, the child code block should end with `exit()` not continue to execute around the loop

Comment: OT: the `delay() function returns the variable `z`, but that returned value is being ignored in the `main()` function

Comment: Somewhere in the 'parent', before exiting the program, it should be calling `wait( NULL ) in a loop, until the returned value is `-1`

Answer (score 2):

Most systems have limits on the number of subprocesses that can be created. These are either system-wide limits or per user limits. If you fork in an infinite loop you are likely hitting such limits.

On Linux, you need to check the ulimit command.

Comment: May I ask if setting the ulimit in LINUX just terminate the program immediately? What I understand from this question was that they wanted me to let the program run indefinitely and whether it is possible. Also, I don't think you answered the question about the code aspect.

Comment: ulimit tells you ahve the limits are.

Comment: Isn't the limits to force your program to go to termination?

Comment: when your call to `fork()` fails, the program is not cleaning up and exiting,  so even though the call to `fork()` fails, the program keeps right on. trying to fork() in all the children and in the parent

Comment: why would the instructor tell you to run such a program?  What it effectively does is lock everyone else out of the computer